# Makefile - replace in wildcard

Tags: c++, makefile

In my project all .cpp files are stored in

```
Classes/
Classes/Something/
Classes/Something/Else
...
```

I want to compile all .cpp file separetly to Bin/ directory, replacing / with _, so that:

```
Classes/First.cpp -> Bin/Classes_First.o
Classes/Foo/Bar.cpp -> Bin/Classes_Foo_Bar.o
```

Now I wanted to create rules for compiling:

```
Bin/%.o: $(subst _,/,%.cpp)
    $(COMPILER)g++ $(COMPILE_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
```

I tried:

make Bin/Classes_Test.o

But compilation failed.

So I created debugging pattern:

```
%.cpp:
    @echo CPP: $@
```

Now it printed:

```
CPP: Classes_Test.cpp
```

Why?!

So I changed my pattern to:

```
Bin/%.o: $(subst _,/,Test1_Test2.cpp)
```

and I saw:

```
CPP: Test1/Test2.cpp
```

I'm a little bit confused why subst does not work if I use wildcard as source...

Answer (score 0):

This is an evaluation order issue.

When make parse the makefile it evaluates the `$(subst)` call but the argument to `$(subst)` at that point is the literal string `%.cpp` which has nothing to substitute in it and so does not do anything.

At target evaluation/execution time the `%` in the target pattern and prereq pattern are filled out but the `$(subst)` has long-since gone away.

To do this you will need to manually (in one way or another) map the output files to the input files. You can do that and keep the `%.o` pattern rule target for the actual recipe to run though (so you just need to generate a bunch of `Bin/Test1_Test2.o: Test1/Test2.cpp` lines).

Alternatively, I believe you can might be able to use [secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) to do this:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
Bin/%.o: $$(subst _,/,%.cpp)
```